# hyperlink on equation number

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I would like to link an equation to a sentence at the end of the document (e.g. code below) but placing the hyperlink on the equation number and not on the equation itself? Is it possible?
THanks for your help.

```
\begin{equation}
  \hyperlink {label1} {
   uWiT = min( TDec_{y-1} , TJan_{y} , TFeb_{y} )}
\end{equation}


...

...

\hypertarget{label1}{Equation minimum temperature}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to insert the hyperlink to the equation number itself, requiring to make a small redefine how the equation number is printed, basically nothing is changed, apart from the underlying hyperlink

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}        



\begin{document}



\begin{equation}
\let\OriginalEquation\theequation%
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\hyperlink{label1}{\OriginalEquation}}%
   uWiT = min( TDec_{y-1} , TJan_{y} , TFeb_{y}) 
\end{equation}


\newpage % for 'end of document' page 
\hypertarget{label1}{Equation minimum temperature}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Other way around I think, the link should go from equation to sentence.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am not really sure, but I made an mistake definitely ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer and TorbjørnT: Perfect !! Thanks!